# Is this possible to extract the human readable content from html src?

Tags: java, html

The HTML is a markup language, mix with lots of things. But all I want to extract the human readable data from the web site to do some content analysis. But all I can see is the html code only. I can extract all the HTML tags one by one to extract the text, and image out. (At least ,I can grep most of the data, but not the javascript inserted data) Instead of doing this, can I have a more efficient way to do so? Thanks.

***Using java as the programming language

Comment: What (programming) language? Most languages have some package for *stripping* HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite thing to use for general website scraping is the BeutifulSoup extension. Here is a link to its documentation. Section 2.1 is parsing HTML code!

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try rendering the web site as plain text using a terminal mode browser such as lynx and then do the content analysis on the output of that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated and well structured your HTML is you might be able to create some XSLT http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/ to transform the HTML into something more readable.